# Blank field not working correctly in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model described as follows-

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=True,blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

All of the fields are required as blank is set to False in each of them but still, I am able to save objects for this model by leaving city and country as blank.

Comment: That is not that strange, `blank=...` are enforced for `ModelForm`s, it is not enforced at the model layer.

Comment: So if I am not using modelForm to map form values to the django model and instead, directly creating model instances in views, it wouldn't work?

Comment: indeed. A `ModelForm` serves multiple purposes: it removes boilerplate code, it can be rendered to a HTML form, and it performs validation (and thus checks `blank=False`).

Comment: Yeah, as per the documentation, it includes two layers of validation, one at the form level and other at the model instance level.

Comment: but the validation at the model layer is not (proactively) done. You can call `.clean()` to do some validation on the model, but the valdiation is skipped by default for performance reasons.

Comment: so saving the form object will do form validation only but we can call methods such as `.clean()` to perform some kind of validation ?

Comment: it will call the validators on the fields, etc. But the model can not check for `blank=True`, since it can have `default=...` values in place that are used. `blank=True` is something "form-oriented". The reason that it is defined in the model is to make it more convenient to define multiple forms for the same model.

Comment: yes that is correct. But `full_clean()` etc. of a model are not called before saving to the database (if not done by the form).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216275/discussion-between-rahul-gusai-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blank=True` is enforced at the `ModelForm` layer, as is specified in the [documentation on the **`blank=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> Note that this is different than `null`. `null` is purely database-related, whereas `blank` is validation-related. If a field has `blank=True`, **form validation** will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has `blank=False`, the field will be required.

So a `ModelForm` that uses this model will raise errors when you do not enter a value for `name`, `city`, and `country`. But not the model layer. In fact the model layer does not validate *any* constraints, unless you call `.clean()`, or the database rejects the values.